# D3 - Center and scale sector on map

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am having some issues that I can not seem to sort out, For the sake of keeping this simple I will only use some stock examples to explain what I am looking to do.

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5126418 -- This basic functionality

What i am looking to do is when a "Tract" is clicked on the map is hidden and the selected Tract is centered on the screen and expanded

My problem is that every time I try this the selected object is just pushed off the screen.

I am sure I am doing something wrong I am new to D3 and have only been using it for a few days

```
.on("click", function(d){
    svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("id", "tract")
    .append("g")
    .attr("id", "wrapper")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data([d])
  .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", path)
    .attr("id", "tract"),
d3.select("#wrapper")
            .transition()
            .duration(800)
            .ease("cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.150, 0.860)")
            .attr("transform", "scale(" + 3 + "), translate(" + (width/2) + ", " + (height/2) + ")");
})
```

This has been driving me nuts so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you looked at this example? http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206590

Comment: Adam, I have looked at that but I am not looking to zoom into the map Instead I want to hide the main map and only extract and center the selected trac, I have tried to use that example and alter it but to no avail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm also very new to d3 - will try to explain how I understand it but I'm not sure I got everything right.

The projection has the concept of a center, given in map units:

> projection.center([location])
>
> If center is specified, sets the projection’s center to the specified location, a two-element array of longitude and latitude in degrees and returns the projection. If center is not specified, returns the current center which defaults to ⟨0°,0°⟩.

There is also the translation, which is where in the screen the projection center stands, in pixels.

> projection.translate([point])
>
> If point is specified, sets the projection’s translation offset to the specified two-element array [x, y] and returns the projection. If point is not specified, returns the current translation offset which defaults to [480, 250]. The translation offset determines the pixel coordinates of the projection’s center. The default translation offset places ⟨0°,0°⟩ at the center of a 960×500 area.

The secret is knowing that some methods operate on the cartographic space and others on the canvas.

In order to center a feature in the canvas, like to set the projection center to the center of the feature bounding box - this works for [mercator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection) (WGS 84, used in google maps), not sure about other projections.

For example, given a projection and path:

```
var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
    .scale(1);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);
```

The `bounds` method from `path` returns the bounding box **in pixels**. Use it to find the correct scale, comparing the size in pixels with the size in map units (0.95 gives you a 5% margin over the best fit for width or height):

```
var b = path.bounds(feature),
    s = 0.95 / Math.max(
                   (b[1][0]-b[0][0])/width, 
                   (b[1][1]-b[0][1])/height
               );
```

Use the `d3.geo.bounds` method to find the bounding box in map units:

```
b = d3.geo.bounds(feature);
```

Set the center of the projection to the center of the bounding box:

```
projection.center([(b[1][0]+b[0][0])/2, (b[1][1]+b[0][1])/2]);
```

Use the `translate` method to move the center of the map to the center of the canvas:

```
projection.translate([width/2, height/2]);
```

By now you should have the feature in the center of the map zoomed with a 5% margin.

Comment: Yep That actually ended up doing it, I ended up getting it to work before reading this but you are correct.